# Meaning of "DMC" abbreviation in LED footprint

Tags: led, footprint

I'm planning on using the SU CULDP1.VC UVC LED for a design, and I'm reading through the datasheet. In the package drawing of the component (p 12 of the datasheet, which can be found here: https://look.ams-osram.com/m/1ac875d09772cda8/original/SU-CULDP1-VC.pdf) the datasheet points out something in the footprint of the component with the abbreviation "DMC". What does DMC stand for here?

[image]

Comment: https://ams-osram.com/support/tools has a "Dot matrix code (DMC)" tool. Don't know if related (and not interested in creating an account with the just to look at it).

Comment: @Mat Given that it's on the same side as the unit marking, and in a similar spot between two pads, it seems like a very likely possibility. I'm guessing they might be able to print the unit marking and dot matrix code in one pass if that's the case.

Comment: Ah, thanks alot, that seems very likely to be what it means!